# Nginx filtering headers with a hash

Tags: nginx

We have a header which is not being passed by Nginx downstream. My guess is that it is due to the hash in it. Is there any way to have this be acknowledged and passed by Nginx?

`java-user-property-#tmc`

Comment: Cross posted [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/742476/nginx-filtering-headers-with-a-hash).

Comment: Please add code context